# Does EF have an event system where you can modify a model before it is saved?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using EF 6.

What I am looking for, is for all my models, I want to modify the model just before it is either created or updated.

Is there an event that I could hook into to make this easy?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using the `DbContext` API then you can override the `SaveChanges` method where you can use the `ChangeTracker` to get the tracked entites and do your custom logic based on the returned `DbEntry.State` property ([`EntityState` enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitystate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<YourEntity>())
        {
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
               // do something with entry.Entity
            }
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
            {
               // do something with entry.Entity
            }
            // etc.
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not forget to override both methods - `SaveChanges` and `SaveChangesAsync`.